# Bad operand types for binary operator - Pythagoreum triples

Tags: java, pythagorean

I am trying to figure out why this code is not working.  I am trying to get the Pythagoreum triples, `1-500`, where the output values are distinct.

When I try to compile, I get an **error message** saying

> error: bad operand types for binary operator.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Pythagoras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int side1;
        int side2;
        int hypotenuse;
        for(side1 = 1; side1 <= 500; side1 ++)
            for(side2 = 1; side2 <= 500; side2 ++)
                for(hypotenuse = 1; hypotenuse <= 500; hypotenuse ++)
                    if(side1 < side2 < hypotenuse)
                        if((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2) == (hypotenuse * hypotenuse))
                            System.out.printf(%d %d %d\n, side1, side2, hypotenuse);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code to reflect the loop and if nesting. This is simply not comprehensible.

Comment: side1 < side2 < hypotenuse doesn't work in Java

Comment: To me, the question is clear and well asked. The question body could be better formatted and highlighted, but its fine. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues which need to be fixed:

1. Blank spaces should never separate unary operators such as increment ("++"), and decrement ("--") from their operands.
2. `a < b < c` is an invalid statement, and you need to use `(a < b && b < c)`

You can also get rid of the comparison (`side1 < side2 < hypotenuse`) by simply updating your for loops as shown below.

Updated implementation:

```
public class Pythagoras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int side1;
        int side2;
        int hypotenuse;
        for(side1 = 1; side1 <= 500; side1++)
            for(side2 = side1+1; side2 <= 500; side2++)
                for(hypotenuse = side2+1; hypotenuse <= 500; hypotenuse++)
                    if((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2) == (hypotenuse * hypotenuse))
                        System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", side1, side2, hypotenuse);

    }


}
```

Comment: @TheScientificMethod It compiles for me, https://ideone.com/CKd0rC. I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: That's insane. Can you provide me any documentation regarding that. All my life, I have used `==` to compare primitive integers in Java.

Comment: Check these resources:

[Java official documentation] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/difference-between-equals-method-and-equality-operator-java.html